# can i use pocos with mongodb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I was wondering if I can read and write raw pocos to mongodb

the driver tutorial shows adding each field to a bsondocument one at a time. Does bsonserialzer do it?

I can write something myself to reflect on an object but I wonder it it already exists.

Working with dynamic expandos would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the 10gen official [C# MongoDB driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center) supports POCO serialisation and deserialisation, e.g.

```
MongoCollection<Thing> thingCollection = _db.GetCollection<Thing>("things");
Thing thing = col.FindAllAs<Thing>();
col.Insert(new Thing { Name = "Foo" });
```

Comment: tx - does it do expandos too?

Comment: No, as far as I know there's no support yet for serialisation or deserialisation of dynamic types.

Comment: Does FindAll support interfaces? i.e IThing thing = col.FindAllAs<IThing>();

Answer (score 2):

I think you can and you should, 10gen driver POCO objects. You can design your POCO model in a completely sepparate assembly without any reference to Mongo.Driver o Mongo.BSon and configure the entry point of your app to use that assembly, setting indexes, ingnore fields, discriminators, ids columns, and a large etc.

```
 BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Post>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.SetIdMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.IdPost));
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.TimeStamp);
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.DatePostedFormat);
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.IdPostString);
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.ForumAvatar);
            cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.ForumAvatarAlt);
        });
```